# Set ServiceBus trigger behavior parameters separately per trigger

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to leverage Azure Functions v2 for large integrations solutions, involving many functions that will process service bus messages.  My plan was to house all of the functions for a given application domain in the same Function App.  I find myself wanting to control the maximum number of concurrent executions of a given function differently depending on the queue/subscription being processed - I may have one Function that is ok to run hundreds or thousands concurrently, and I may have others that I don't want more than one or two.  Unless I am missing something, it looks like the host.json controls for ServiceBus trigger behavior are FunctionApp-wide (and really in an integrations project all of those behaviors could need to be tuned differently per trigger).  If this is so, are there plans to enable more granular trigger behavior controls?

Answer (score 1):

We don't have plans to do so. Trigger and binding responsibilities are managed by the [Azure Functions Host](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host), which runs the code of one entire Function App.

Our recommendation here is to create multiple Function Apps, that have different host.json configurations. You won't incur more cost, and you can deploy your function apps in the same [resource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview) for easier management.